# Tabulating dataframe in R with summary statistics

Tags: r

Here is a toy data.frame:

```
sex = c(rep("M", 4), rep("F", 4))
bg = c(rep("W",2),rep("NW",2),rep("W",2),rep("NW",2))
income = c(156,185,105,115,95,78,67,74)
(data = data.frame(income, sex, bg))

  income sex bg
1    156   M  W
2    185   M  W
3    105   M NW
4    115   M NW
5     95   F  W
6     78   F  W
7     67   F NW
8     74   F NW
```

I am looking for a way to turn this object into a cross-table with, for example, the mean in every cell:

[image]

Comment: Why is the site better off with this question closed? Can you give me the courtesy to explain with a short sentence, preferably non-disparaging?

Comment: OK, gentlemen. It is duplicated. Fair, enough. So closing may be in order, but also down-voting?

Comment: I didn't downvote.  I thought it was a good question, but yes definitely a duplicate. I think you might have been downvoted because you didn't show any attempts to solve it yourself.

Comment: Some individuals really misuse the power of downvoting here.

Comment: The good thing is, it's only 2 points :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using this code:

```
library(reshape2)

dcast(df,bg ~ sex,fun.aggregate = mean,value.var='income')

##  bg    F     M
##1 NW 70.5 110.0
##2  W 86.5 170.5
```

Comment: It would be nice to know why this was downvoted.

Comment: Dear Downvoter, can you please elaborate on how can I improve this solution?